# Excel VBA to scan directory contents and update table

Tags: vba, excel

I've been making a vba script to scan the contents of a directory and update a table with the results of that scan. The results are that a file is Unchanged, New, or Missing, which is updated into the File Status column of the table. If it's new, then it will put the filename into the Filename column of the table.

I have the code fairly close but I'm having trouble with some of the logic going through the two arrays. I've exhausted my ability to look at this without causing more problems in the code, further changes are causing regressions in the code.

Can anyone have a look at the code, see if I'm on the right path or if there's a simple mistake I've made? It's incorrectly marking as some files missing or new where it shouldn't be, but I believe it's correctly marking the Unchanged files first before anything else goes wrong.

```
Sub FolderContents()

Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile As Object
Dim g, h, i, j, k, l As Integer
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim FileArray(), FileStatusArray() As String
Dim wsName, tbName, fnName, fsName, Path As String
Dim colNumFile, colNumStatus As Long
Dim newRow As ListRow
h = 1
j = 1
l = 1

' Change only these values if name of table or worksheets change
wsName = "Signage List"     'Worksheet name that contains the signage table
tbName = "Signage"          'Table name for the signage file data
fnName = "Filename"         'Column name that contains the file names
fsName = "File Status"      'Column name that contains the file statuses

' ! DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE !

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).ButtonName = "Select Folder"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select destination folder"
    If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        Path = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
End With

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Path)
Set myTable = Worksheets(wsName).ListObjects(tbName)
colNumFile = myTable.ListColumns(fnName).Index
colNumStatus = myTable.ListColumns(fsName).Index

If Not myTable.ListColumns(colNumFile).DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    myArray = myTable.ListColumns(colNumFile).DataBodyRange
End If

If Not IsEmpty(myArray) Then
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFile.Type = "PNG image" Then
            For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
                ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To j)
                ReDim Preserve FileStatusArray(1 To j)
                If myArray(i, 1) = objFile.Name Then
                    FileArray(j) = objFile.Name
                    Cells(i + 1, colNumStatus) = "Unchanged"
                    FileStatusArray(j) = "Unchanged"
                    GoTo NextFile
                Else
                    FileArray(j) = objFile.Name
                    FileStatusArray(j) = "New"
                End If
            Next i
NextFile:
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next objFile

    For k = LBound(FileArray) To UBound(FileArray)
        For l = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
            If Not myArray(l, 1) = FileArray(k) Then
                Cells(l + 1, colNumStatus) = "Missing"
                GoTo AnotherFile
            Else
                    Cells(l + 1, colNumStatus) = "Unchanged"
            End If
            Next l
AnotherFile:

        If FileStatusArray(k) = "New" Then
            Set newRow = myTable.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
            Set myTable = Worksheets(wsName).ListObjects(tbName)
            newRow.Range.Cells(1, colNumStatus) = "New"
            newRow.Range.Cells(1, colNumFile) = FileArray(k)
        End If
    Next k
Else
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFile.Type = "PNG image" Then
            ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To h)
            ReDim Preserve FileStatusArray(1 To h)
            FileArray(h) = objFile.Name
            FileStatusArray(h) = "New"
            h = h + 1
        End If
    Next objFile

    For g = LBound(FileArray) To UBound(FileArray)
        Set newRow = myTable.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
        Set myTable = Worksheets(wsName).ListObjects(tbName)
        newRow.Range.Cells(1, colNumStatus) = "New"
        newRow.Range.Cells(1, colNumFile) = FileArray(g)
    Next g
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over a range or array several times, I prefer to add the values to a dictionary.  I also try and break large sub routines into smaller tasks.

```
Sub FolderContents()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Change only these values if name of table or worksheets change
    Const wsName = "Signage List"    'Worksheet name that contains the signage table
    Const tbName = "Signage"      'Table name for the signage file data
    Const fnName = "Filename"     'Column name that contains the file names
    Const fsName = "File Status"  'Column name that contains the file statuses
    Dim dImageFiles
    Dim tblSignage As ListObject
    Dim newRow As Range
    Dim k As String

    Dim x As Long, colNumFile As Long, colNumStatus As Long

    Set dImageFiles = getSignageImageFilesDictionary

    If dImageFiles.Count = 0 Then
        ' Do Something if no folder was selected
    End If

    Set tblSignage = Worksheets(wsName).ListObjects(tbName)

    With tblSignage
        colNumFile = .ListColumns(fnName).Index
        colNumStatus = .ListColumns(fsName).Index
        With .DataBodyRange
            For x = 1 To .Rows.Count
                k = .Cells(x, colNumFile).Text
                If dImageFiles.Exists(k) Then
                    .Cells(x, colNumStatus) = "Unchanged"
                    dImageFiles.Remove k
                Else
                    .Cells(x, colNumStatus) = "Missing"
                End If

            Next x

        End With
    End With

    For x = 0 To dImageFiles.Count - 1
        Set newRow = tblSignage.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True).Range
        newRow.Cells(1, colNumFile) = dImageFiles.keys(x)
        newRow.Cells(1, colNumStatus) = "New"
    Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function getSignageImageFilesDictionary()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim dict, fso, f

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    folderPath = getFolderPath
    If Len(folderPath) Then
        For Each f In fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Files

            If fso.GetExtensionName(f.Path) = "png" Then
                If Not dict.Exists(f.Name) Then dict.Add f.Name, f.Path
            End If

        Next
    End If

    Set getSignageImageFilesDictionary = dict
    Set fso = Nothing
End Function

Function getFolderPath() As String

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).ButtonName = "Select Folder"

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select destination folder"
        If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
            getFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else: Exit Function
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

I didn't see any reason to use arrays.  If you were dealing with a large amount of data I would have created one multi-dimensional array by transposing the table's databodyrange.  It needs to be transposed because only the last dimension of an array can be resized.    Next can values of the array and add new rows to it. Finally, we transpose the array over the existiong databodyrange.

```
Sub FolderContents()
    ' Change only these values if name of table or worksheets change
    Const wsName = "Signage List"        'Worksheet name that contains the signage table
    Const tbName = "Signage"          'Table name for the signage file data
    Const fnName = "Filename"         'Column name that contains the file names
    Const fsName = "File Status"      'Column name that contains the file statuses
    Dim dImageFiles
    Dim tblSignage As ListObject
    Dim k As String
    Dim x As Long, count As Long, colCount As Long, colNumFile As Long, colNumStatus As Long
    Dim arData, v

    Set dImageFiles = getSignageImageFilesDictionary

    If dImageFiles.count = 0 Then
        ' Do Something if no folder was selected
    End If

    Set tblSignage = Worksheets(wsName).ListObjects(tbName)

    With tblSignage
        colNumFile = .ListColumns(fnName).Index
        colNumStatus = .ListColumns(fsName).Index
        colCount = .DataBodyRange.Columns.count

        arData = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.DataBodyRange)

        For x = 1 To UBound(arData, 2)

            k = arData(colNumFile, x)
            If dImageFiles.Exists(k) Then
                arData(colNumStatus, x) = "Unchanged"
                dImageFiles.Remove k
            Else
                arData(colNumStatus, x) = "Missing"
            End If
        Next x

        For Each v In dImageFiles.keys()
            count = UBound(arData, 2) + 1
            ReDim Preserve arData(1 To colCount, 1 To count)
            arData(colNumFile, count) = v
            arData(colNumStatus, count) = "New"
        Next v

        .DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arData, 2), colCount) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arData)

    End With

End Sub
```